# boost ptree add_child creates undesired nested element

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I need help adding a child ptree node to an existing ptree node that already
contains a value. The problem I am facing is that I end up with a
`current_module` nested within an existing `current_module`

The way I am trying to achieve this is as follows:

```
std::vector<moduleStatus> moduleStatii = {
    {"mod1", "file1.TXT", 0x0002}, 
    {"mod2", "file2.TXT", 0x0003}
};

ptree pt;
pt.add("status.session_id", sessionID);
pt.put("status.start_time", timeStringUTC);
pt.put("status.load_file", loadFile);
pt.put("status.upload.estimated_loadtime", 1983);
pt.put("status.upload.time_remaining", 1613);   // not finished - non-zero
// for each over the modules...
for (const auto& next : moduleStatii) {
    ptree moduleStatus;
    moduleStatus.put("current_module", next.moduleName);
    moduleStatus.put("current_module.current_file", next.currentFile);
    moduleStatus.put("current_module.status_code", next.statusCode);
    pt.add_child("status.upload.current_module", moduleStatus);
}
// this is overall status - operation in progress 0x0002
pt.put("status.status_code", ss.str());
write_xml(std::cout, pt, settings);
```

Unfortunately, the output is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<status>
  <session_id>123</session_id>
  <start_time>Sat Sep 26 20:12:46 2015</start_time>
  <load_file>/tmp/filename.zip</load_file>
  <upload>
    <estimated_loadtime>1983</estimated_loadtime>
    <time_remaining>0</time_remaining>
    <current_module>
      mod1
      <current_file>file1.TXT</current_file>
      <status_code>3</status_code>
    </current_module>
    <current_module>
      mod2
      <current_file>file2.TXT</current_file>
      <status_code>3</status_code>
    </current_module>
  </upload>
  <status_code>0x0002</status_code>
</status>
```

My live [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b6c5e5199ffde77) shows my current output as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<status>
  <session_id>123</session_id>
  <start_time>Sat Sep 26 20:23:38 2015</start_time>
  <load_file>/tmp/filename.zip</load_file>
  <upload>
    <estimated_loadtime>1983</estimated_loadtime>
    <time_remaining>1613</time_remaining>
    <current_module>
      <current_module>
        mod1
        <current_file>file1.TXT</current_file>
        <status_code>2</status_code>
      </current_module>
    </current_module>
    <current_module>
      <current_module>
        mod2
        <current_file>file2.TXT</current_file>
        <status_code>3</status_code>
      </current_module>
    </current_module>
  </upload>
  <status_code>0x0002</status_code>
</status>
```

Unfortunately it contains an extra level of nesting that I cannot seem to
avoid. The key thing to note is that there is a value associated with the
`</current_module>` - in the example `mod1` and `mod2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do not specify the extra parent path nodes:

```
    ptree moduleStatus;
    moduleStatus.put_value(next.moduleName);
    moduleStatus.put("current_file", next.currentFile);
    moduleStatus.put("status_code", next.statusCode);
    pt.add_child("status.upload.current_module", moduleStatus);
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e09ef65af960adb)**

Prints

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<status>
  <session_id>123</session_id>
  <start_time>Sat Sep 26 21:29:06 2015</start_time>
  <load_file>/tmp/filename.zip</load_file>
  <upload>
    <estimated_loadtime>1983</estimated_loadtime>
    <time_remaining>1613</time_remaining>
    <current_module>
      mod1
      <current_file>file1.TXT</current_file>
      <status_code>2</status_code>
    </current_module>
    <current_module>
      mod2
      <current_file>file2.TXT</current_file>
      <status_code>3</status_code>
    </current_module>
  </upload>
  <status_code>0x0002</status_code>
</status>
```